# Pyside6, открываем сайты под системное оформление

Tags: python, pyside6

Как научить pyside6 открывать сайты с системным оформление винды.
если нажать альт + шивт + принскрин запускается темное офрмление винды и все сайты в темном оформление(гугл хром, опера)
если открывать на pyside6 сайты открываются в белом оформление.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73060080/4711135